# Вставка php-кода в html-документ посредством include

Tags: include, php, html

Уважаемые учасники. Обращаюсь к вам с банальный вопросом - нужно для удобства div-блоки типа шапка, менюшки и т.д. вставлять как php вставки, так как сайт делается вручную без цмс и предусмотрено много страниц с контентом, который время от времени надо редактировать на всех страницах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильней всего сделать? Я понимаю, что надо создавать отдельный пхп-файлы с кодом, который надо вставить. Меня интересует, в каком формате должен заноситься код и формат внедрения его в хтмл-документ. Спасибо.

Вот код шапки и т.д.

```
    <div id="hmenu" style="height:80px;">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current first" href="index.html">О нас</a></li>  
        <li><a href="#">Дизайнерам</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Наши друзья</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

              <h2>Наши партнеры</h2>

                    <div class="news">
                        <div id="news" class="scroll-pane">

                    <ul>
                        <li>- <a href="mmebel.html">Ссылка 1</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>  
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                        <li>- <a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="hmenu" style="height:80px;">
   <?php include_once 'hmenu.php' ?>
</div>

<h2>Наши партнеры</h2>
<div class="news">
    <div id="news" class="scroll-pane">
        <?php include_once 'news.php' ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Документ должен быть HTML.

Comment: И вы получите ошибку при интерпретации!

     **<?php**

     <div id="hmenu" style="height:80px;">
     <?php include_once 'hmenu.php' ?>
     </div>

     <h2>Наши партнеры</h2>
     <div class="news">
      <div id="news" class="scroll-pane">
         <?php include_once 'news.php' ?>
    </div>
    </div>
   **?>**

Comment: исправил,молодец!

Answer (score 1):

ну в своем самом простом проявлении можно сделать что-то типа

```
function viewInit($view) {
    $viewPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/view/' . $view . '.html';
    if(file_exists($viewPath)) {
        // если файл $view.html лежит на сервере в папочке view 
        include_once $viewPath;
    }
}
```

Теперь небольшой пример, допустим у нас есть шаблон **top.html** и шаблон **foo.html**

И мы пишем скрипт вывода новостей, то тогда делаем примерно следующее

Скрипт news.php

```
// подключение к БД
$dbResult = 'SELECT * FROM news';
$newsAll = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult) ) { 
    $newsAll[] = $row; // собираем все новости в массив
}
// теперь инициализируем шиблон
viewInit('newsAll'); // подключаем шаблон newsAll.
```

Собственно шаболон:

```
<!-- подключаем вер html'я -->
<?viewInit('top')?>

<!-- ну а тут какнить выведем новости -->

<div id="newsAll">
    <?foreach($newsAll as $news):?>
       <div class="newsTitlte">
         <?=$news['title']?>
       </div>
       <div class="newsContent">
         <?=$news['content']?>
       </div>
    <?endforeach?>

</div>

<!-- подключаем футер -->
<?viewInit('foo')?>
```

Собственно самое простое что мог придумать, если интересует ООП реализация - спрашивайте.

Именно по вопросу php кода в "чистом html'e" - по-моему находил такой модуль для апача.
PS: веб сервер нужен однозначно...

PPS: как можно догадатся вложенность шаблонов может быть любая, т.е. например в том-же top.html могут подключатся другие шаблоны, например preheader, header, topnav и т.д.

Comment: спасибо, отлично описали, полезно и интересно. но мне в данном случае не нужно сильно заморачиваться - сайтик небольшой, елементов для вставки мало. нужно что-то проще)

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно еще в .htaccess добавить:

```
AddType x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

И тогда .html будет как и .php интерпретироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Если нельзя заменить расширение основного файла с .html на .php:

## include virtual="file.php"

Пишется строчка в нужном месте html-файла В КОММЕНТАРИИ. Вместо "file.php" может быть любой файл (в том числе и еще один html).

Answer (score 0):

по крайней мере главный файл, который будет инклудить блоки должен быть сохранен формате в php, иначе он не поймет просто конструкцию <?php include 'header.php' ?>. А раз главный на php значит Вам уже нужен веб-сервер.

Comment: этот этап учебы уже пройден) мне нужна структура и синтаксис данного процеса - как сделать правильно, чтобы все отображалось.

Comment: насколько я понял, допустим, файл index.html при внедрении пхп-кода нужно переименовать в index.php? И так все документы, где будет использоваться инклуд?

Comment: Да. Или менять .htaccess, как описано выше.